# "Bad configuration option: ServerAliveInterval" using Net::OpenSSH and Solaris SSH client

Tags: perl, ssh, openssh

I'm trying to use [`Net::OpenSSH`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) to connect to a remote host:

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(
    $ip_address,
    user => $user,
    password => $password,
    timeout => 3600,
    master_opts => [ -o => "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" ],
    ctl_dir => $ENV{HOME}
);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: ServerAliveInterval
Unable to connect to remote host: unable to establish master SSH connection: bad password or master process exited unexpectedly at t1.pl line 33.
```

I'm using the following version of the SSH client:

```sh
$ ssh -V
SSH Version Sun_SSH_1.0.1, protocol versions 1.5/2.0.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The real error is the first one, about `ServerAliveInterval`. What version of OpenSSH do you have (run `ssh -v` to find out)?

Comment: Thanks for reply ... i am using SSH Version Sun_SSH_1.0.1, protocol versions 1.5/2.0.

Comment: if you have any solution for the same. please reply...

Comment: crosspost at http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1097550

Answer (score 1):

`Net::OpenSSH` doesn't support the Solaris SSH client. From the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#Solaris-and-AIX-and-probably-others):

> The SSH client bundled with Solaris is an early fork of OpenSSH that does not provide the multiplexing functionality required by Net::OpenSSH. You will have to install the OpenSSH client.

[Install the OpenSSH client](http://unixpackages.com/support/help/help-installing-openssh) and ensure that it appears *before* the system `ssh` in your path.

Alternatively, use the [`ssh_cmd`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#ssh_cmd-cmd) option to `new`:

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, ssh_cmd => '/usr/local/bin/ssh');
```

Comment: sunfreeware.com is asking to download whole sparc package. Is there any other way out in perl to execute the commands on the remote windows machine and get the output on local machine? Please help....

Comment: @user3914863 There are other ways to get OpenSSH, that just happened to be the place recommended in the `Net::OpenSSH` documentation. See [Installing OpenSSH Packages for SPARC and x86/Solaris 8-11](http://unixpackages.com/support/help/help-installing-openssh).